# Is there a way to find out if the content of an iframe has changed?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, page-refresh

I am looking for a way in js to check every x seconds if the content of my iframe has changed, and if so, refreh it to see the changes.
I want to do this because simply refreshing every x seconds makes it very visible and forces the iframe to return to the top of the scrollbar every time.
The src of the iframe is on the same domain so I have no problems with the same-origin policy.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple. Make Ajax calls to retrieve the content of the page at a specified time interval. Compare the new content length with the previous one and reset the `src` attribute of `iframe` if there's any difference.

```js
const URL = 'https://stackoverflow.com';
let content = '';
setTimeout(() => {
  $.ajax({
    url: URL,
    type: 'GET',
    success: (res) => {
      if (content.length !== res.length) {
        content = res;
        $('#myframe').attr('src', URL);
      }
    },
    error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
      console.error(textStatus);
    }
  });
}, 5000); // Check difference and refresh iframe in 5 seconds interval
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="myframe" src="https://stackoverflow.com"></iframe>
```